# How to Align using CSS - Beginner request

Tags: html, css

I just started learning HTML and CSS recently and I wanted to try creating a login page. I have managed making something that's pretty basic, however the input boxes and labels are not aligned and it looks unprofessional. If possible I'd like an advice as to how I should fix this using CSS.

Here's my code :

```html
<br /> UserName:
<input type="text" name="user name" size="15" />
<br /> Password:
<input type="text" name="password" size='15' />
<input type="text" hidden name="Password" size="15" /> <br />
<input type="reset" value="Login" />
<input type="submit" value="Cancel" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nxgm33y7/8/

Comment: By align do you mean in the middle of screen or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to change your markup a bit so that you get some space to play around with your element positioning. I've created a simple example here, make sure you use classes and ids to select the elements.

What I am doing below is, wrapping all the elements in a `div` element, think of it as a wrapper, so that whenever you want to move your form in the middle of the page, it will be easy for you to do so.

Next, I use `ul` and `li` elements, this will help you render each of the form fields one below the other. Next, we use `label` tag, so that you can set some default `width` for them, and your form elements will stay aligned.

Lastly, I am using this selector `ul li:last-child input:first-child` which you can safely replace with a simple `class`. It's used to nudge your first `button` i.e *login* to align with other form elements.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul li:last-child input:first-child {
  margin-left: 85px;
}

label {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="reset" value="Login" />
      <input type="submit" value="Cancel" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use [Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) for more professional look and it gives responsive layout. Anyway here i have used normal css. Please check out the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/5zg2qqum/ . Try this:

HTML:

```
<body>

    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
    <label style="width:50%;">UserName:</label>
    <input type="text" name="user name" size="15" class="form-input"/>
    </div>

    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
    <label style="width:50%;">Password:</label>
    <input type="text" name="password" size='15' class="form-pswd"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Password" size="15" /> <br />
    </div>

    <br>
  <div align="center" style="width:100%;">
    <input type="reset" value="Login" />
    <input type="submit" value="Cancel" />
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.form-group{

  width:100%;margin-left:5%;
}

.form-input{
  width:50%;margin-left:5%;
}

.form-pswd{
  width:50%;margin-left:6%;
}
```